# .NET BinarySearch() on ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: .net, search, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of custom objects that have the following properties:

- FileName
- FilePath
- CurrentFolder
- TopLevelFolder

I then need to do a BinarySearch (or some other quick search) on the FileName property on all the objects in the ArrayList in .NET. In other words, I need to find the object in the ArrayList with the same FileName as the one I'm searching on.

Syntax for the ArrayList's BinarySearch is this; but how do you do this for an object's property in the arraylist?

```
  public static void FindMyObject( ArrayList myList, Object myObject )  {
    int myIndex=myList.BinarySearch( myObject );
    if ( myIndex < 0 )
       Console.WriteLine( "The object to search for ({0}) is not found. The next larger object is at index {1}.", myObject, ~myIndex );
    else
       Console.WriteLine( "The object to search for ({0}) is at index {1}.", myObject, myIndex );
  }
```

Comment: Why `ArrayList` instead of `Dictionary<string,TValue>`? Are you using .net 1.x?

Comment: What's the advantage of Dictionary object?

Comment: 1) O(1) lookup and 2) compile time type safety.

Comment: And `ArrayList` is practically obsolete since .net 2 and replaced by `List<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of Areay.BinarySearch that takes a comparer ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba2bttb.aspx ), but in this case I would simply switch to a `Dictionary<string,YourType>`, which sounds far more appropriate:

- faster fetch: O(1)
- no dependency on the data being sorted (in fact, no notion of sorting at all)
- strongly typed

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I'm coming back to .NET after being away for awhile. The Dictionary seems the best choice. How do you do the search in this case?

Comment: @Alex - `var item = dict[key];`, or `dict.TryGetValue(key, out item)` (and test the return value is `true`).

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I'm implementing this now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, Marc. Working like a charm. I'm also now looping over the Dictionary using the `KeyValuePair()`. And it runs like the wind. More examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx   Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement comparer class, and you should use specific class type not just object for example I'd created a class C and do custom search:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<C>
{
    #region IComparer<C> Members

    public int Compare(C x, C y)
    {
        return x.filename.CompareTo(y.filename);
    }

    #endregion
}
 public class C
 {
        public string filename;
        public string id;
 }
```

and use it:

```
 List<C> aList = new List<C>();
 aList.BinarySearch(myCObject, new MyComparer());
```